# Android : Restrict apk file to install Only in Devices Which Uses HDPI & MDPI images.

Tags: android, image, device, apk, restriction

I have One Project Which is Already Implemented in IPhone(more than 2 yeas ago). Now i just have that Source code to build this same application in Android. Due to some reason Client Does Not have Image Source Files right Now. So Right Now I just have images with resolution of 320*460 pixels to make application for android.

**What Is My Problem :**  as we does not have high Resoultion images supported for xhdpi supported devices. Client Wants to restrict Application only for HDPI supported Screens not for xhdpi Supported Screens. First I just want to Know that Is it Possible to make apk file Supported only for Devices that Uses HDPI Images? and If Possible How can i do that?

**What I have Searched :**  i have searched in StackOverflow but could not able to get my Problem Solved.

**QUESTION** : So How can I Restrict my APK file to  Install only in Devices which Uses HDPI & MDPI Images. it should not be installed if Device Uses XHDPI images.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to restrict your `apk` file from installing in xlarge screens

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="false"
                      android:xlargeScreens="false" />
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For more information, look at the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Comment: Thnks for your Support. i just want to know one more thing. if i have phone which is having high resoultion like galaxy nexus(Which Uses HDPI images) then it will install in it or not?

Comment: I think in your case, you should look more to <compatible-screens> tag. <support-screens> tag set the restriction in screen width context while <compatible-screens> look more into density pixel that your application support (e.g HDPI and MDPI).

Comment: i think it will depend on how large the phone screen size is. Looking at the documentation, you can specify support to separate screen densities the same screen sizes. I think you should look at the `<compatible-screens>` tag. Check the official documentation page I provided for that